# What is the "substantial difference" that might occur in the google shares?

Tags: google

What is the "substantial difference" that might occur between the google shares?

Comment: You offer a quote with no context. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're talking about the different share class introduced in the recent [stock split](http://blogs.marketwatch.com/thetell/2014/04/02/google-investors-are-about-to-get-goog-and-googl-shares-in-stock-split/), which mean that there are now three Google share classes:

- Class A, ticker symbol GOOGL, one vote per share
- Class B, not traded publically but owned by current and former Google employees, 10 votes per share
- Class C, ticker symbol GOOG, no votes

Due to the voting rights, Class A shares should be worth more than class C, but how much only time will tell. Actually, one could very well argue that a non-voting share of a company that pays no dividends has no value at all. It's unlikely the markets will see it that way, though.

Comment: Not sure why the voting shares matter in this case, Brin and Page still control over 50% of the vote with their B shares.